# Displaying an MDList in my kivymd file doesn't work

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working on a project with python and kivymd and i want to display an MDList in my file kv (list.kv)
but it doesn't work , i don't know where is the problem !! any suggestions
this is main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from mysql.connector import Error
from baseclass.start import Start
from kivy.lang import Builder  
from threading import Thread
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from spin_load import ProgressSpinner
from kivymd.color_definitions import colors
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
import mysql.connector
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.properties import OptionProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDListBottomSheet
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem


Window.size = (360, 600)


class Codebarre(Screen):
    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(20):
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}")
            )        
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")

MyApp().run()
```

and this is the file where i want to display the MDList

list.kv

````
#:import utils kivy.utils

<Codebarre>:
    name: 'codebarre'
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: container ```
````

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the `on_start()` method was never called. A working version of `main.py` is below. I didn't change `list.kv`.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from threading import Thread
import kivy.clock
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivymd.color_definitions import colors
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.properties import OptionProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.bottomsheet import MDListBottomSheet
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout


Window.size = (360, 600)


class Codebarre(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        self.app = MDApp.get_running_app()
        super().__init__(**kvargs)
        kivy.clock.Clock.schedule_once(self.build)

    def build(self, *args):
        for i in range(20):
            self.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}")
            )        

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple"
        Builder.load_file("list.kv")
        return Codebarre()

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: by this way you have deleted the file main.kv that contains other screen , i have more than one screen , and i return Builder.load.file('main.kv') for accessing to all the screen , i hope you understand me

Comment: Sorry - I didn't know there was another .kv file. I had to make minor changes to your code to get it to run. To load "mail.kv" also, just add `Builder.load_file("main.kv")` above the existing `load_file`.